# Expectation of the log of a ratio of two lognormal random variables with additive constants

Tags: distributions, variance, expected-value, lognormal-distribution, logarithm

I have two independent lognormal random variables $X$ and $Y$ with known means and variances. I would like to know the expected value and the variance of $\ln\big((X+1)/(Y+1)\big)$. If there is no exact solution, is there a means of approximation?

I have tried a Taylor expansion on $\ln(X+1) - \ln(Y+1)$ as suggested in an answer to the question [Expected value of a natural logarithm](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/38296/expected-value-of-a-natural-logarithm). Unfortunately, the Taylor expansion does not provide a good estimate for one of the lognormal random variables I am working with.

To provide more detail on the problem and in particular the failed Taylor expansion, I have $X=\exp\big((m-Z)/v\big)$ where $Z$$\sim$$N(\mu,\sigma^2)$ with constants $m>0$ and $v>0$. This implies:

$E[X]=\exp\big(\frac{m-\mu}{v} + \frac{1}{2}(\frac{\sigma}{v})^2\big)$

and

$V[X]=\Big[\exp\big((\frac{\sigma}{v})^2\big) - 1\Big]\centerdot\exp\big(2\frac{m-\mu}{v} + (\frac{\sigma}{v})^2\big)$.

If I run a simulation where I set $\mu=9024$ and $\sigma=600$ to generate a large sample of $n$ random variates of $Z$, and using R code `mean(log(exp((m - Z)/v) + 1))` to take the average of the $n$ by $\ln(x+1)$ variates with $m=8900$, $v=400$, by the central limit theorum I get $E\big(\ln(X+1)\big)\approx0.7784$. However, plugging those values into the Taylor expansion I get:

$E\big(\ln(X+1)\big)\approx\ln(E[X] + 1) - \frac{V[X]}{2(E[X]+ 1)^2}\approx-0.8577$.

Comment: Note that (because of how order of operations works), the expression $\ln(X+1/Y+1)$ actually means $\ln(X + Y^{-1}+1)$ not $\ln(\frac{X+1}{Y+1})$ (which I believe is what you want). Can you say more about the failure of the Taylor expansion? It might provide useful context.

Comment: Thanks for the correction Glen_b, that is what I had intended. I have edited my post to provide information about the failed Taylor expansion.

Comment: This is not a trick question with X, Y i.id, correct? i.e.: X, Y do not necessarily have the same mean and variance.

Comment: @Victor If they had identical distributions, then obviously the expectation would be $0$--but it is still challenging to determine the variance.

Comment: Hi Victor. No X and Y are not i.id. they are both lognormal but with different means and variances.