# Expectation of the log of a negative random variable

Tags: expected-value

I read the following result based on a second order Taylor expansion (here: [Expected value of a natural logarithm](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/38296/expected-value-of-a-natural-logarithm))

$$\mathbb{E}(\log(x)) = \log(\mathbb{E}(x))-\frac{1}{2}\frac{\mathbb{V}\text{ar}(x)}{\mathbb{E}(x)^2}$$

If we assume that $x\sim N(\mu,\sigma^2)$ then
$$\mathbb{E}(\log(x)) = \log(\mu) - \frac{\sigma^2}{2\mu}.$$
What I would like to know is what happens if the random variable is negative and we want the expectation of its log, i.e., what is $\mathbb{E}(\log(-x))$.

Is the following correct?

$$\mathbb{E}(\log(x)) = \log(-\mu) + \frac{\sigma^2}{2\mu}.$$ Or should we still be subtracting $\sigma^2/2\mu$?

Comment: Because logarithms of negative numbers are undefined, the Normal example in the question makes no sense.

Comment: I just want to confirm that you understand that the log of a negative number is multi-valued and complex.

Comment: @John That would take us off on an irrelevant tangent.  In statistical applications, it suffices to remember that logarithms can be meaningfully applied only to positive numbers.

Comment: @whuber Our posts were simultaneous; I was addressing the OP :)

Comment: @whuber that is fine. In fact, given the application that I am using this for, it is actually important for me to know when () is not a real number. However, ignoring that fact, my question is specifically with regards to whether or not the last term should be subtracted or added? You can just ignore the $x\sim N()$ fact and just use the general expectation and variance operators instead.

Comment: @JohnSmith it's just that, even for the case E[log(x)] with x Normal, since the probability that x < 0 is positive for any mu\inR and sigma2>0, the expectation is never a real number; rather its some infinite collection of complex numbers. Thence whuber's suspicion that this isn't what you're really looking for.

Comment: @JohnMadden it's a very specific application for a constrained optimization problem. My surface is being modeled using a  normal distribution and the $\log(-x)$ is a penalty function that helps identify when I am not satisfying the constraints. So anywhere that $x$ is thought to be $>0$ is a bad thing and I want it to be that way. But again my question is more concerned with the last term being added versus subtracted.

Comment: OK I'll prepare an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, this expectation is ill defined.

But even just mechanically, no, you don't need to add, it's still subtraction, as you can verify by checking that $\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2} log(x) = \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2} log(-x)$.

We can check the series expansions of both in mathematica:

[image]