# Can $e^{E(\log(x))}$ be calculated approximating $E(\log x) $ using a second order Taylor expansion around the mean?

Tags: expected-value, approximation

While searching around, I found this question
[Expected value of a natural logarithm](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/38296/expected-value-of-a-natural-logarithm)
dealing with the expected value of the natural log.
The top answer references a paper that approximates the expected value of the natural logarithm of x using a second order Taylor expansion around the mean.
What about if I'm interested in $e^{E(\log(x))}$
Would I just plug in the result of that second order asymptotic expression into the exponential function and compute that, to give me an answer? Is it that simple or am I missing?

Comment: Could you clarify what information you're starting with? If we say that $Y=\log(X)$ are you starting with knowledge of $E(Y)$? or of $E(X)$? (Where does this population-level knowledge come from?)

Comment: I cannot make much sense of the question, because $E[\log x]$ is a *number* and one would calculate its exponential in any standard way.